Library 'GoogleSignIn' not found
I'm working on an iOS app that was functioning perfectly before I added Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to implement push notifications. The Android side is still working flawlessly after integrating FCM, but the iOS version won't build anymore. Every time I try to run the app in Xcode, I encounter the same error.
enter image description here
here are some of my files
# Enable modular headers globally
use_modular_headers!
def node_require(script)
   # Resolve script with node to allow for hoisting
   require Pod::Executable.execute_command('node', ['-p',
     "require.resolve(
       '#{script}',
       {paths: [process.argv[1]]},
     )", __dir__]).strip
 end

# Use it to require both react-native's and this package's scripts:
 node_require('react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb')
 node_require('react-native-permissions/scripts/setup.rb')


platform :ios, min_ios_version_supported
prepare_react_native_project!

setup_permissions([
  'LocationAlways',
  'LocationWhenInUse',
])

linkage = ENV['USE_FRAMEWORKS']
if linkage != nil
  Pod::UI.puts "Configuring Pod with #{linkage}ally linked Frameworks".green
  use_frameworks! :linkage => linkage.to_sym
end

use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
$RNFirebaseAsStaticFramework = true

target 'OfferBoat' do
  
  rn_maps_path = '../node_modules/react-native-maps'
  pod 'react-native-google-maps', :path => rn_maps_path
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(
    :path => config[:reactNativePath],
    # An absolute path to your application root.
    :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
  )

   # Add GooglePlaces and GoogleMaps pods here
   pod 'GooglePlaces'
   pod 'GoogleMaps'

  target 'OfferBoatTests' do
    inherit! :complete
    # Pods for testing
  end

  post_install do |installer|
    # https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/packages/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods.rb#L197-L202
    react_native_post_install(
      installer,
      config[:reactNativePath],
      :mac_catalyst_enabled => false,
      # :ccache_enabled => true
    )
  end
end

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Firebase.h>
#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FIRApp configure];
  [GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"AIza...iY4.....Y...nYj...Q3G...g"];
  self.moduleName = @"OfferBoat";

  // You can add your custom initial props in the dictionary below.
  // They will be passed down to the ViewController used by React Native.
  self.initialProps = @{};
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
{
  return [self bundleURL];
}

- (NSURL *)bundleURL
{
#if DEBUG
  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];
#else
  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
#endif
}

@end

enter image description here
I added GoogleService Info.plist file like this .
here is my package.json file
{
  "name": "OfferBoat",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.5.0",
    "@notifee/react-native": "^7.8.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^8.1.0",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^3.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^20.4.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^20.4.0",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^12.2.1",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.20",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.26",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.5",
    "@stripe/stripe-react-native": "^0.38.2",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.33",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "date-fns": "^3.6.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "^6.7.2",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.5",
    "react-native": "0.74.2",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1305.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.16.2",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.41.1",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.15.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^13.0.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^17.1.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "latest",
    "react-native-phone-number-input": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-ratings": "^8.1.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.12.0",
    "react-native-reanimated-carousel": "^3.5.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.10.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.31.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^10.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "yup": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "0.74.84",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "0.74.84",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.18",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.4"
}

and yes I also added these capabilities in xcode
enter image description here
I'd appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance!
Steps I've Taken:
Ran pod install --repo-update to ensure all dependencies are up to date.
Deleted Pods and Podfile.lock, then reinstalled pods using pod install.
Cleaned the build folder in Xcode (Product > Clean Build Folder).
Deleted the contents of /Users/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/.
Despite these efforts, the build error persists.

Maybe install the library?
pod 'GoogleSignIn'
pod install

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating

I added, but still got same error

With the pod installed, it is supposed to find it; that pod is even supposed to be there already. Better file an issue there: https://github.com/react-native-google-signin/google-signin/issues

ok so i update my podfile like this, and its solve my issue

